# The .properties file is getting overridden. How to overcome from that?

Tags: java, properties, config

The config.properties file in java is getting overridden after every execution. What I want is, The previous data should also be saved with the new updated one.

Below is the code which i have used to store the value to config.properties file. And my config.properties file already contain some data.

```
try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("path\\to\\config.properties")) {

            Properties prop = new Properties();

            // set the properties value
            prop.setProperty("IFCode", "34253");

            // save properties to project root folder
            prop.store(output, null);

            System.out.println(prop);

        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And here is my config.properties file data which is already present there:-

```
#Tue Jul 23 02:38:34 EDT 2019
File=987
Read=098
```

Now, when I run the above code these already available data is getting omitted and the new one is getting written like this:-

```
#Tue Jul 23 02:38:34 EDT 2019
IFCode=34253
```

What I want basically is:-

```
#Tue Jul 23 02:38:34 EDT 2019
File=987
Read=098
IFCode=34253
```

How to overcome this problem using java?

Comment: Read the properties, add a property to it, then write the properties. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-

Comment: Is the file opening in write mode instead of append mode? You can try checking it.

Comment: i am not opening file while data is being stored there. Only thing is, the previous data is being lost. Need solution for this. i have used config.save() also. But no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the boolean append parameter for your FileOutputStream:

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("path\\to\\config.properties", true)
```

> FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append) 
>   Creates a file output stream to write to the file represented by the specified File object. Check for reference:
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

Comment: This worked but what if, I want to to override the value whose Key is already present in the config.properties file. Like this:- #Tue Jul 23 02:38:34 EDT 2019
File=987
Read=098
IFCode=34253 and next time run it then the IFCode is getting generated again like this:- #Tue Jul 23 02:38:34 EDT 2019
File=987
Read=098
IFCode=34253 IFCode=9868

Comment: In that case, then you need to 1. open the file, 2. read properties from the property file, 3. check if the property exists, if so, change the value for that key, else append.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
  try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("path\\to\\config.properties",true)) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();

    // set the properties value
    prop.setProperty("IFCode", "34253");

    // save properties to project root folder
    prop.store(output, null);

    System.out.println(prop);

}  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```